# jQuery and JavaScript selectors not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm quite a noob in jQuery and JavaScript and I've got the following script written in Javascript that I want to change and also convert to jQuery:

```
  new AnimOnScroll( document.getElementById( 'grid' ), {
    minDuration : 0.4,
    maxDuration : 0.7,
    viewportFactor : 0.2
  } );
```

The above code works but when I try to write this in jQuery with the following code, it doesn't work:

```
new AnimOnScroll( $('#grid'), {
  minDuration : 0.4,
  maxDuration : 0.7,
  viewportFactor : 0.2
} );
```

Also I am trying to change the script so that I can get it to work on multiple places on my page, so instead I want to select the elements by ClassName and not Id, like so:

```
  new AnimOnScroll( document.getElementClassName( 'grid' ), {
    minDuration : 0.4,
    maxDuration : 0.7,
    viewportFactor : 0.2
  } );
```

This code also doesn't work and my text editor (Sublime text 2) doesn't even highlight 'getElementClassName' but it does highlight 'getElementById'.

Can someone please help me with this, I'm really lost. Thanks.

PS. the code is from http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/02/loading-effects-for-grid-items-with-css-animations/comment-page-2/#comments

Comment: It is `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementClassName`

Comment: You should google instead of typing random function names.

Comment: 1.  Have you included the jQuery library in the page?
2.  Have you included the AnimOnScroll library in the page, from https://github.com/derekck/animOnScroll/blob/master/src/animOnScroll.js ?

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I was able make it with with the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because that code is meant to work with a DOM element, not a jQ object. Add a `[0]` to the end of your jQuery and it should work: `$('#grid')[0]`

Comment: _"with a JS object"_ - With a _DOM_ element. jQuery objects are JS objects.

Comment: Hey, I just realized that if I have $('.grid')[0], I am only able to work with the first element of the class grid. Can you please also tell me how can I have it so that it selects all the elements with the class .grid and not just the second one or the third one. Thanks!